grafana add 2 metrics on dashboard
how do i show 2 metrics on one dashboard?
example like this
enter image description here
and the metrics should be like this
windows_cs_physical_memory_bytes{instance=~"$server"} + "/" + windows_os_physical_memory_free_bytes{instance=~"$server"}
i tried to add more query but it looks like this
enter image description here

I don't recall this being possible with default panels. Where did you get the screenshot from? Inspecting source of that panel will reveal how it was done.
